# How boxplot over absolute error of learning models could be used to compare\evaluate learning models' performances?

Tags: model-evaluation, boxplot, mae

Recently I crossed this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11227-022-04782-z) which represents the evaluation of various models' performances within a single dataset by Boxplot over $Absolute~Error~(AE)$ as follows:

| [image: img] |
| --- |
| Fig. 12: Boxplot of baseline methods for our method and previous studies for M1. [ref](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11227-022-04782-z/figures/12) |

Normally we use $Mean~Absolute~Error~(MAE)$ or $Mean~Square~Error~(MSE)$, etc for different models comparison.

I have checked this post: [Box Plot Explained with Examples](https://statisticsbyjim.com/graphs/box-plot/) but still there some considerations like:

- **Central Tendency** [Measures of Central Tendency](https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/measures-central-tendency-mean-median-mode/) & [Median: Definition and Uses](https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/median/)
- **Variability** [Measures of Variability](https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/variability-range-interquartile-variance-standard-deviation/)
- **Skewness**: [Skewed Distributions](https://statisticsbyjim.com/basics/skewed-distribution/)

My question:

- How this representation can be interpreted? (knowing that *the lower the error, the better model*)
- Does it mean that instead of using $mean$ or $average$ of error calculation e.g. $Mean~Absolute~Error~(MAE)$ by bar plot, one can just collect all error estimations during learning and plot **box plot**? then which extra information can translate that classical **bar plot** over MAE could not?

I can not figure it out what is the benefits and logic behind it.

---

potentially related posts:

- [Absolute Error as a tool to evaluate model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228316/240550)
- [Is it cheating to drop the outliers based on the boxplot of Mean Absolute Error to improve a regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/263238/240550)
- [Can model variance be concluded using boxplot of error estimates?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/275552/240550)
- ['Absolute' benchmarks of model performance on dataset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/623935/240550)
- [Mean absolute error vs sum absolute error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43470/240550)
- [Minimum "recommended" sample size for boxplots? Boxplots for different sample sizes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/194842/240550)
- [How should we do boxplots with small samples?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/582496/240550)